# Ask Ubuntu for mobile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, browser

I was away from my home computer and I wanted to check Ask Ubuntu for any notifications, so I decided to check from my mobile phone. The interface isn't too bad for browsing on a mobile phone but it would be great to have a mobile-optimised version of the website (or an app) for those people who can't reach their computer.

Is there any plans (if possible) to construct a version of the website specifically for mobile browsers? I know it probably won't be possible but it would be really great if so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the "mobile" link at the bottom of the main page. Great mobile version of the site with support for posting.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of mobile apps (and other cool tools) for this site here:

- https://stackapps.com/

Comment: Cool! Should have looked harder, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com/).

Comment: I visited this site yesterday But it just displayed API error ,But now it is ok :)

Comment: It has been having some problems with the API's rate-limit. I'm still trying to come up with a good solution for the problem.